# magento not getting actual ip address in order

Tags: php, magento, ip, magento-1.7, opayo

I am facing a very different issue in magento 1.7 CE

Issue is

I am using sage pay with magento 1.7 CE for payment. So when a user place order some time magento get local ip in this condition my payment shows as test and in some conditions magento get external ip in this condition payment shows as live. While in both condition payment received in vendor account on sagepay.
I checked many order and found the same.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem on the IP, you have old TEST transactions on sagepaysuite_transaction table.

Please backup the table and delete rows where mode = TEST so this problem is solved.

Kind Regards,

Pablo